# EthereumのGeth JavaScriptコンソールでminer.startを実行するとエラーが出る

Tags: ubuntu, ethereum

OSはUbuntuを使用しています。
https://book.ethereum-jp.net/
上記のドキュメントを参考にGethをプライベートネットワークで起動した後
miner.start()のコマンドを実行するとそれぞれ下の画像のエラーコードが出る
[image: mindf.start()を入力したときのエラーコード]

web3はインストール済み